# F# remove trailing space

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have this method that takes in a list and turns it into a bytecode string. It works the way I expect; however, I get one trailing space that I do not want. **Question:** how do I get rid of this last trailing 0?

```
Input: byteCode [SC 10; SC 2; SAdd; SC 32; SC 4; SC 5; SAdd; SMul; SAdd]

let rec byteCode (l : sInstr list) : string = 
  match l with 
  | [] -> "" 
  | (SC    n :: l)     -> "0 " + string n + " " + byteCode l 
  | (SAdd    :: l)     -> "1 " + byteCode l 
  | (SSub    :: l)     -> "2 " + byteCode l 
  | (SMul    :: l)     -> "3 " + byteCode l 
  | (SNeg    :: l)     -> "4 " + byteCode l 
  | (SLess   :: l)     -> "5 " + byteCode l 
  | (SIfze n :: l)     -> "6 " + string n + " " + byteCode l 
  | (SJump n :: l)     -> "7 " + string n + " " + byteCode l
```

This probably won't compile because I didn't give my entire program.

```
This returns: "0 10 0 2 1 0 32 0 4 0 5 1 3 1 "
I expect:     "0 10 0 2 1 0 32 0 4 0 5 1 3 1"
```

Comment: well, since you haven't even given input and I don't see how the given code cant even print 15, it will be difficult for us to figure this out

Comment: The type declaration of `sInstr` would be helpful. Please try to always give code examples that compile, so people wanting to help you don't unnecessarily have to chase for hints.

Comment: fundamentally you dou `"1 " + something` and `something=""` so you get `"1 "`.  Easiest solution is probably to just run trimend

Comment: I don't understand how to do that with recursive pattern matching

Answer (score 6):

Cases like this are usually signs that strings are concatenated in a way that is too naive. Consider first collecting all the individual components of your result and then calling the predefined `String.concat` function:

```
let byteCode (l : sInstr list) : string = 
    let rec byteCode' l =
        match l with 
        | [] -> []
        | (SC    n :: l)     -> "0" :: string n :: byteCode' l
        | (SAdd    :: l)     -> "1" :: byteCode' l
        | (SSub    :: l)     -> "2" :: byteCode' l
        | (SMul    :: l)     -> "3" :: byteCode' l
        | (SNeg    :: l)     -> "4" :: byteCode' l
        | (SLess   :: l)     -> "5" :: byteCode' l
        | (SIfze n :: l)     -> "6" :: string n :: byteCode' l 
        | (SJump n :: l)     -> "7" :: string n :: byteCode' l

    l |> byteCode' |> String.concat " "
```

`String.concat` already only adds the separator string *between* the individual parts.

This is also much cleaner, because it keeps the implementation detail of the specific separator string out of your core logic and makes it much more easily replaceable - imagine the effort of simply changing it to two spaces in your function.

Alternatively, you can just use your existing function, and on the final resulting string call the `.Trim()` (or `.TrimEnd()`) method to remove (trailing) spaces.

Comment: The outer byteCode function should not be rec then

Comment: In addition to the advantages you cited, this is also more efficient because `String.concat` uses a `StringBuilder` to create the resulting string, which is better than chaining concatenations.

Comment: @HenrikHansen That is correct; I forgot to remove that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid recursion in this manner:

```
let byteCode (l : sInstr list) : string = 
  let instrToString (bc : sInstr) : string =
    match bc with 
    | (SC    n) -> sprintf "0 %d" n
    | (SAdd   ) -> "1"
    | (SSub   ) -> "2"
    | (SMul   ) -> "3"
    | (SNeg   ) -> "4"
    | (SLess  ) -> "5"
    | (SIfze n) -> sprintf "6 %d" n
    | (SJump n) -> sprintf "7 %d" n

  l |> List.map instrToString |> String.concat " "
```

Supposed sInstr is defined as:

```
type sInstr =
| SC of int
| SAdd
| SSub
| SMul
| SNeg
| SLess
| SIfze of int
| SJump of int
```

the functions to byteCodes and revserse could look like this:

```
let byteCode (l : sInstr list) : string = 
  let instrToString (bc : sInstr) =
    (match bc with 
    | SC    n -> [0; n]
    | SAdd    -> [1]
    | SSub    -> [2]
    | SMul    -> [3]
    | SNeg    -> [4]
    | SLess   -> [5]
    | SIfze n -> [6; n]
    | SJump n -> [7; n])

  String.Join(" ", (l |> List.map instrToString |> List.fold (fun acc lst -> acc @ lst) []))

let toInstr (bcString : string) : sInstr list = 
  let rec recToInstr bcList = 
    match bcList with
    | [] -> []
    | head :: tail -> 
        match head with
        | "0" -> SC(Int32.Parse(tail.[0])) :: recToInstr (tail |> List.skip 1)
        | "1" -> SAdd :: recToInstr tail
        | "2" -> SSub :: recToInstr tail
        | "3" -> SMul :: recToInstr tail
        | "4" -> SNeg :: recToInstr tail
        | "5" -> SLess :: recToInstr tail
        | "6" -> SIfze(Int32.Parse(tail.[0])) :: recToInstr (tail |> List.skip 1)
        | "7" -> SJump(Int32.Parse(tail.[0])) :: recToInstr (tail |> List.skip 1)
        | _ -> []

  recToInstr (bcString.Split(' ') |> Array.toList)
```

Comment: True (though I still wouldn't add the separators inline to avoid duplication). The recursive approach would be much more important for implementing the opposite direction.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev: What do you mean by duplication? - and opposite direction?

Comment: Duplication: The `sprintf` calls include the space character used as a separator in multiple places, so changing (or just determining) that would be more involved and error prone. With "opposite direction", I mean parsing the "bytecode" produced here back into the original representation. Because an operation may or may not have an argument, not every step would shorten the list by the same number of elements, so one couldn't just use `map´.